# Getting error when integrating cloudera hue with ldap server?

Tags: openldap, cloudera

I have configured ldap server on centos machine.I am able to execute ldapadd and ldapsearch sucessfully. But while integrating ldap with cloudera hue getting following error

> RuntimeError: Failed to bind to LDAP server as user cn=Manager
>   [02/Mar/2015 09:11:22 -0800] middleware   INFO     Processing
>   exception: Failed to bind to LDAP server as user cn=Manager: Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 111, in get_response
>       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/lib/hue/apps/useradmin/src/useradmin/views.py", line 408, in sync_ldap_users_groups
>       connection = ldap_access.get_connection_from_server(server)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/lib/hue/apps/useradmin/src/useradmin/ldap_access.py", line 41, in get_connection_from_server
>       return get_connection(desktop.conf.LDAP, search_bind_authentication=desktop.conf.LDAP.SEARCH_BIND_AUTHENTICATION.get())
>   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/lib/hue/apps/useradmin/src/useradmin/ldap_access.py", line 57, in get_connection
>       return LdapConnection(ldap_config, ldap_url, username, password, ldap_cert)   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/lib/hue/apps/useradmin/src/useradmin/ldap_access.py", line 119, in **init**
>       bind_user) RuntimeError: Failed to bind to LDAP server as user cn=Manager [02/Mar/2015 09:11:22 -0800] access       INFO
>   10.43.3.110 admin - "POST /useradmin/users/sync_ldap_users_groups HTTP/1.1" [02/Mar/2015 09:11:16 -0800] access       INFO
>   10.43.3.110 admin - "GET /useradmin/users/sync_ldap_users_groups HTTP/1.1" [02/Mar/2015 09:11:05 -0800] resource     DEBUG    GET Got
>   response: {"apps":null} [02/Mar/2015 09:11:05 -0800] connectionpool
>   DEBUG    "GET /ws/v1/cluster/apps?user=admin&finalStatus=UNDEFINED
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 None

I have configured cloudera hue as follows

```
Authentication Backend desktop.auth.backend.LdapBackend
LDAP URL - ldap://10.77.36.37
LDAP Username Pattern- uid=<username>,ou=Users,dc=persistent,dc=com
search_bind_authentication - true
LDAP Search Base - dc=persistent,dc=com
bind_dn - cn=Manager
user_name_attr- uid
```

is there anything missing in above configuration. ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> > Failed to bind to LDAP server as user cn=Manager

It could be something as simple as making sure LDAP bind username and passwords are correct.